# Laravel Eloquent casted array field pull results that have some of the submitted ids

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a table called `recipes` that has a field cast to an array that houses ids from another table `ingredients`. A user can select from a form, specific ingredients they want to see recipes for.

Is there a way I can take the submitted list of ids and only pull recipes that have some of those ids? I say some because I don't want to limit to recipes that have only ALL of the ids. Meaning if someone chooses chicken, onions, and celery and there are recipes that contain those ingredients plus carrots, peppers and mushrooms I want to show those as well.

The only query I can come up with seems to compare exact to exact.

```
$recipes = Recipes::whereIn('ingredient_ids', $request->ingredient_ids)->get();
```

With `ingredient_ids` being the list of submitted ingredients.

Comment: Might be worth creating a new table `recipe_ingredients` with rows `recipe_id | ingredient_id`

Answer (score 0):

I know that you cast the field as an `array` but this might work: If your database is MySQL or PostgreSQL you could make use of [`whereJsonContains()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses).

From the docs:

> MySQL and PostgreSQL support `whereJsonContains` with multiple values:
>
> ```
> $users = DB::table('users')
>             ->whereJsonContains('options->languages', ['en', 'de'])
>             ->get();
> ```

So try this in your code:

```
$recipes = Recipes
       ::whereJsonContains('ingredient_ids', $request->ingredient_ids)
       ->get();
```